# Cannot use the "Alt-C" app on Android phone and Mac laptop

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I bought a Samsung Galaxy A71 recently then I installed an app called [Alt-C](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.canobakedbeans.instacopy) on my phone and my MacBook air. It works fine, but the app cannot copy text from my own phone to my Mac, and a message appears on my phone, saying:

> Alt-C could not paste text to PC: make sure you copied the text on your device.

and a notification appears on my Mac saying:

> there was no text in the device's clipboard.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem and it seems that since Android 10, apps can only access the clipboard if they are in the foreground. So the only way for the copy to work from Phone to Mac is to open the app on your phone after you've copied the text, and then paste on the Mac.

Comment: ah, makes sense for security I guess. Better than nothing. iOS and MacOS clipboard sync is so good I missed this feature when I went android.

Comment: I just tested Alt C on Android 11 and it works in the background, at least when I've recently opened it. It wasn't working before that though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Alt C works on Android 11 if you've recently opened it on your phone, or if you allow it to keep use battery in the background.

For the latter, the ways to do this vary - here's an [example for Pixel phones](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/6068458/how-to-keep-apps-running-in-the-background?hl=en). I haven't tested this thoroughly with Alt C.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 12, I faced the same issue where I was able to copy text from PC to phone but not able to copy text from phone to PC, it showed "couldn't paste text from realme", but later I found the way to copy text from phone to PC.

Basically, when you copy text from your phone then you have to open the Alt-C app in order to sync with your PC, and when the app is open on your phone, then you try to paste it on your PC, then it will be paste. It worked for me in Android 12.